# sound cloud track id url scheme and web

Tags: ios, web, soundcloud, url-scheme

I have a push notification arriving into my iOS app that has the track id. I'm able to successfully open the sound cloud app to the right track, but I would like to open that track in mobile safari if the device doesn't have the sound cloud app installed. Below is the code i'm using:

```
NSString *soundCloudApp = @"soundcloud:tracks:";
NSString *soundCloudUrl = @"https://api.soundcloud.com/tracks";
NSURL *fanPageURL = [NSURL URLWithString:[soundCloudApp stringByAppendingString:data]];
if (![[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL: fanPageURL]) {
   //fanPageURL failed to open.  Open the website in Safari instead
   NSURL *webURL = [NSURL URLWithString:[soundCloudUrl stringByAppendingString:data]];
   [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL: webURL];
}
```

The problem is if i inter something like https://api.soundcloud.com/tracks/my_track_id sound cloud returns unauthorized access. if i try https://soundcloud.com/tracks/my_track_id i get a page not found. Any way i can open the track in safari given only the track id?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `permalink_url` property of track representation.

Comment: I didn't really want the app to look up information or have to obtain a client id and make API calls to resolve information. Is there something i can send down in the push notification that will let me open the track directly in both the sound cloud app and safari?

Comment: I don't think you could land user to a sound page without having sounds permalink, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should use in your "if" statement

```
if (![[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL: fanPageURL])
{
//open safari
}
```

Comment: I think the question has to do more with can I open a track in safari given the track id (as opposed to track name)?